# Multidimensional array to text using only keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array of this sort:

```
$array = [
        "Darren" => [
            "age" => "18",
            "work" => [
                "occupation" => "developer",
                "company" => "ABC Ltd"
            ]
        ],
        "John" => [
            "age" => "24",
            "work" => [
                "occupation" => "developer",
                "company" => "ABC Ltd",
                "url" => "www.example.com"
            ],
        ]
    ]
```

And would like to merge the keys with a dot in between, depending on the array's hierachy:

```
       "Darren.age"
       "Darren.work.occupation"
       "Darren.work.company"
       ...
```

The function that I made so far is

```
    public function buildExpressionKey($array, $parentKey = null){

        $expression = [];

        foreach($array as $key=>$value){

            if(is_array($value)){
               array_push($expression, $parentKey. implode(".", 
$this->buildExpressionKey($value, $key)));
           }else{
               array_push($expression, $key);
           }
       }

       return $expression;
   }
```

it is returning this value at the moment:

```
  [
    [0] => "age.Darrenoccupation.company"
    [1] => "age.Johnoccupation.company.url"
  ]
```

Was wondering if it is possible to make a function which automatically does merges the keys like that, thanks in advance :)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: post first your try

Comment: *it can have more than 2 dimensions* - post the extended input array and show clearly the relations between nested keys

Comment: Are you trying to rename your keys?  To perhaps flatten your multi-dimensional array for some reason?   Give us an example of your expected output, i.e. when it has more than 2 dimensions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need an array\_keys\_recursive()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872840/i-need-an-array-keys-recursive)

Comment: @splash58 No, the other question just wants to echo all keys (with inner keys) in disregard of the structure

Comment: @PhilippMaurer I don't see any diff - OP can print result array :)

Comment: @splash58 The difference is, that the keys do not get concatenated based on the initial structure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get array's key recursively and create underscore separated string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749398/get-arrays-key-recursively-and-create-underscore-separated-string)

Comment: This seems to be the most fitting duplicate

Comment: basically I am trying to build a an expression for DynamoDb. Based on the array it will auto build an UpdateExpression. 

Url is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.PHP.03.html#GettingStarted.PHP.03.03

Answer (score 1):

What you are currently asking for:

```
<?php

$people =
[
 'John' => 
    [
        'Occupation' => 'Developer',
        'Age' => 18
    ],
'Darren' =>
    [
        'Occupation' => 'Manager',
        'Age' => 40
    ]
];


foreach($people as $name => $value)
    foreach($value as $k => $v)
        $strings[] = $name . '.' . $k;

var_export($strings);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'John.Occupation',
  1 => 'John.Age',
  2 => 'Darren.Occupation',
  3 => 'Darren.Age',
)
```

Comment: Quote form the question: **I would like to have a scalable approach which is done automatically via a custom function. So it can have more than 2 dimensions**.

Comment: @PhilippMaurer wrapping the above in a function is trivial.  But I suspect the OP actually wants to do more than generate some strings.  Waiting for corrections/clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve this issue :)

```
/**
 * @param $array
 * @return array
 */
public function buildExpressionKey($array){

    $iterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveArrayIterator($array));
    $keys = array();
    foreach ($iterator as $key => $value) {
        // Build long key name based on parent keys
        for ($i = $iterator->getDepth() - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
            $key = $iterator->getSubIterator($i)->key() . '.' . $key;
        }
        $keys[] = $key;
    }
    return $keys;
}
```

Found something similar on here: [Get array's key recursively and create underscore separated string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749398/get-arrays-key-recursively-and-create-underscore-separated-string)